# Rails 4.2 Nested Forms--SQL Automatically Deleted Nested Forms Content When Loading 'Edit' Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I use this [Blog](http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/) as a guide to learn `nested form` on `Ruby on Rails 4.2`. I tried to create a location nested form within the `Post` model with the same steps from this instruction.

After creating a new `post` with nested location form, the location content was shown correctly on the `post's` show page. However, when I open the `edit` page, the location content is all gone. After inspecting the log carefully, I found below information:

```
Started GET "/categories/category#name/posts/323/edit"...
Location Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."post_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["post_id", 323]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = ?  [["id", 27]]
```

It seems the content created in nested form was deleted by SQL automatically when loading the edit page.

Here is my code:

```
   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :category

      has_one :location, dependent: :destroy

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, reject_if: lambda { |a| a['street'].blank? },
                                     allow_destroy: true
      def to_s
        title
      end
   end
```

Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :user, through: :post


  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :zipcode, presence: true,
             format: { with: /\A\d{5}\z/i }


end
```

PostsController:

```
 class Categories::PostsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def new
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
        @post = Post.new
        @post.build_location
      end

      def create
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        @post.category = @category

        if @post.save
          flash[:success] = "You have succesfully created a new post."
          redirect_to [@category, @post]
        else
          flash[:error] = "Error occured. Please try again."
          render :new
        end
      end

      def edit
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.build_location
      end

      def update
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
          if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
            flash[:success] = "Post was upated."
            redirect_to [@category, @post]
          else
            flash[:error] = "There was an error saving a post, please try again."
            render :new
          end
      end
    ...
    private 

        def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, location_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :zipcode, :_destroy])
        end
```

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@category, @post] do |f| %>
  ...
  <strong>Location:</strong>
  <div class="well">
    <%= f.fields_for :location do |location| %>
      <%= location.label :street %>
  <%= location.text_field :street, placeholder: "If you don't want to provide your address, just put 'NA' in this field" %>

  <%= location.label :city %>
  <%= location.text_field :city %>

  <%= location.label :zipcode%>
  <%= location.text_field :zipcode %>

  <%= location.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= location.label :_destroy, 'remove' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

While everything works well from the instruction I followed, I keep getting the "silent" error in my app when I test it on the server. How can I make the existing data from nested form appear on the edit page?

Any insight is welcomed and thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `edit` action - 3rd line try `@post.create_location` instead of `@post.build_location`

Comment: Tried  @post.create_location but it didn't work.

Comment: try with a bang and please post the server log after that -> `@post.create_location!`

Comment: It still has the same log after adding the bang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your edit method in controller. Build instance only when post doesn't have associated location.

```
@post.build_location if @post.location.blank?
```

Answer (score 2):

`@post.build_location` creates a new location object in memory, and therefore that is getting passed to the `update` and therefore deletes locations associated to the post. It doesn't fetch the current location.

`@post.create_location` also creates a new location object but sames this to the database. This is not what you want.

<s>I would remove the `@post.build_location` from the edit action. The view should work as its already looking for the `location` for the `post` which is same as doing `@post.location`</s>

**Edit**
You probably want the behavior as below:

- If a Post has a Location, show the current Location in the Edit of Post
- If a Post doesn't have a Location, show empty field in the Edit of Post

for this you need to build the Location object in the edit action only when a Post has no Location.

```
 def edit
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.build_location if @post.location.nil?
  end
```

This is what you need in the edit action

Comment: Thanks! But after I remove @post.build_location, it just takes out the whole location fields when I open the edit page again.

Comment: That is the expected location as this indicates that the Post doesn't have a Location. If you want it to show empty fields when there is no location i would if you add the build back in like so `@post.build_location if @post.location.nil?`

Comment: Thanks so much! It works with if @post.location.blank? instead of @post.location.nil, though. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `@post.build_location` it clears your old Location from the database.

Check out the [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one) guide here on "When are objects saved?"

For example:

```
a = Whole.new
a.save
a
=> #<Whole id: 2, name: "foo", created_at: "2015-09-02 05:15:15", updated_at: "2015-09-02 05:15:15">
a.part
=> nil
b = a.build_part
b.save
a.part
=> #<Part id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2015-09-02 05:16:37", updated_at: "2015-09-02 05:16:37", whole_id: 2> 
c = a.build_part
=> #<Part id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, whole_id: 2>
Part.find_by(whole_id: 2)
=> nil
```

You could also only build a new location if there isn't one already:

```
@post.build_location unless @post.location
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide! But can you explain why the example in http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/ still works (without clearing the old record)  while keeping @hotel.room_categories.build in its edit action?

Comment: The tutorial is using a has_many association, which allows you to build and save as many "child" objects as you'd like. It's a particularity of the has_one association that it deletes the old record once you build a new one.